# v-model with condition to the router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

in [this example](https://codepen.io/iTaurus85/pen/aRNWdy), there is a navigation with nested menus.
And when you click "more" you see the list. We can make it open always with v-model="item.model", as model = true.

So what I'm trying to do is to make it stay open only when the user is at the current page of the nested menu.

like this -  `v-model="active-class ? stayOpen : stayOpen = false"`

```
data: () => {
model: true,
stayopen: false
},
methods:{
        stayOpen: function (event) {
          this.stayOpen = true;
          }
      }

            <v-list-group
                 no-action
                 sub-group
                 v-model="active-class ? stayOpen : stayOpen = false"
               >
              <v-list-tile slot="activator"  active-class="tttt">
                <v-list-tile-title>Beginner</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile
                          v-for="(item, i) in beginner"
                          :key="i"
                          :to="item.link"

                          >
                <v-list-tile-title > {{item.text}} </v-list-tile-title>
                <v-list-tile-action>
                  <v-icon ></v-icon>
                </v-list-tile-action>
              </v-list-tile>
            </v-list-group>
```

that doesn't work anyway:(
I just can make it open permanently with `v-model="item.model"`

Comment: You can use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) to calculate whether the user is at the current page of the nested menu, and then use the computed value to decide whether the list should stay open.

Answer (score 0):

when `active-class` is **false**,  it always returns the result of expression `stayOpen = false` whose returning value is constant `false`.